# How to combine angularjs and xhtml?

Tags: angularjs

Here is an example of a minimal example for angularjs which works when saved as `angular.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng:app="">
<head>
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

However I strongly believe in XML and I like to create all my html documents XML compliant. I tried to adapt the example and save it as `angular.xhtml`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng:app="">
<head>
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js" />
</head>
<body>

  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The big changes are the xhtml-Namespace and the file extension ".xhtml". There is no error or anything. It's just that the page is displayed as if angular was not present.

How do I get angularjs working with an XML compliant file?

Comment: You are using an HTML5 instead of a [XHTML Doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Comment: @klingt.net: To my knowledge this is in accordance with the html specification which defines the recommended doctype and also allows delivering HTML5 documents with content type application/xhtml+xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using manual setup. The code then looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', []);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

While this seems a suitable workaround for now, I'd still love to know what the problem is...

Answer (score 5):

One of the best ways to do this is to use the HTML/XHTML `data-` attributes. You can write valid HTML and XHTML without having to include any angular namespace. This would be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="">
<head>
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js" />
</head>
<body>

  <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is also beneficial when it comes to all other Angular declarations, such as `ng-repeat` and `ng-show`, etc.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</div> // This won't validate.
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</div> // This will validate.
```

Note that your solution with bootstrapping the Angular app is also valid - but it's not really a fix for the issue you're having. (It's simply a different way to load your Angular app, which happened to work for your situation since you didn't have any other `ng-` directives in your markup.)

See a similar question and answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19969971/677526)