# 24 hours format in angularjs input[time]

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to display 24 hours format using input[time] component (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D) in angular (without showing AM and PM text)? All examples I found use 12 hours format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Date time in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this demo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-time-input-directive-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="timeExample">
  <script>
 angular.module('timeExample', [])
   .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" placeholder="HH:mm:ss" required />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```

```
<input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" placeholder="HH:mm:ss" required />
```

Comment: Is this for HTML 5 only

Comment: @AaronRabinowitz do you know angular apps that are run with other HTML version than 5?

Comment: fair enough I work at company that for a long time used an old browser

Comment: No but have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185973/how-to-combine-angularjs-and-xhtml

Comment: Hmmm ok! Anyway, if he would like to combine it with xHTML I think he’d have told us

Comment: This may have worked at the time of the answer but now (2023) it displays the same 12-hr format with AM/PM options as a regular <input type="time"> (at least on my machine)